# Continuous images of open sets

Tags: general-topology, continuity

In trying to prove that the graph of a continuous map of compact Hausdorff spaces, $f:X\to Y$ is compact, I stumbled on this problem:

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous function, $U$ and $V$ open in $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Let $A=f(U)\cap V$. Then $U \cap f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X$.

Under what conditions is this true, and can a proof be provided.

Comment: The inverse of a continuous function maps open sets to open sets. The intersection of open sets is open. So you just have to prove that $A$ is open.

Comment: @ruler501: $A$ is *not* necessarily open. For example, let $X = (0,1)\cup (2,3)$ and $Y=\mathbb R$, and define $f:X\to Y$ by $f(x)=0$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and $f(x)=x$ for $x\in (2,3)$. Then for any open $V\subset\mathbb R$ containing $0$, $A=\{0\}$ is not open in $Y$.

Comment: Note also that, if $f$ is not injective, $f^{-1}(A)$ does *not* denote the image of $A$ under the inverse of $f$, as $f$ has no inverse.

Comment: For a simpler counterexample (I can't edit that first comment any more), let $X=Y=\mathbb R$, let $f(x)=x^2$, and let $U=V=(-1,1)$. Then $A=[0,1)$ is not an open subset of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

First, $f(U)$ not necessarily is open, e.g., let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous, but $f(\mathbb{R})=[0,+\infty)$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Sencond, $U\cap f^{-1}(V)$ is open, since $f^{-1}(V)$ is open (since $f$ is continuous) and finite intersection of open is open.

Fnally, $U\cap f^{-1}(A)=U\cap f^{-1}(V)$. Since $f^{-1}(A)\subset f^{-1}(V)$, then $U\cap f^{-1}(A)\subset U\cap f^{-1}(V)$. If $x\in U\cap f^{-1}(V)$, then $f(x)\in V$ and $f(x)\in f(U)$, i.e., $f(x)\in A$. Thus, $$x\in f^{-1}(f(x))\subset f^{-1}(A)\;,$$ so $x\in U\cap f^{-1}(A)$, and this implies that $U\cap f^{-1}(V)\subset U\cap f^{-1}(A)$, showing that
$$
U\cap f^{-1}(A)=U\cap f^{-1}(V).
$$
Therefore, $U\cap f^{-1}(A)$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

The set you are interested in equals $U\cap f^{-1}(V)$, therefore it is open.

Comment: @wckronholm: True, but so what?